# can we define abstract class inside the interface in java?

Tags: java

I am new to this concept, i know the property of interface and abstract.
when i explain the concept to my friends, they asked me to create abstract class inside the interface.

please tell me , is it possible to create abstract class inside the interface.
i googled, but i am not able find the exact answer for my question.

i tried the below code ,but i dont know how to cal the AbstractMethod.

```
interface Student {

    public abstract class Subject {

        public void AbstractMethod(){
            System.out.println("hi");
        }
    }
}

class Data implements Student {

    public void ClassMethod() {
        System.out.println("method 2");
    }
}

public class NewClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Data s=new Data(); 
 Student.Subject obj=new Student.Subject();// compiler error
    s.ClassMethod();
}
}
```

Comment: Well, your so named `AbstractMethod` is not abstract.

Comment: The fact that your code compiles answers the question in your title. 'Don't know how to' is not a problem description.

Comment: If you want to create an implementation you can access the abstract class as `Student.Subject`

Comment: when i tried to call like Student.Subject, the compiler says ,subject is abstract ,it cannot instantiated

Comment: Unacceptable. 'When I tried  to call like `Student.Subject`' is meaningless. You have to post the actual code you tried, and the actual error message.

Comment: Obviously, you can't create an instance of `Subject` because it is an `abstract` class.  If you want to create an instance, you to declare / define a non-abstract subclass of `Subject`.  This is no different to the case where `Subject` is a separate class.

Comment: @stephen, yeah. but i just want to know whether its possible or not.

Comment: @EJP, edited my question with full code. please check it

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't something like this be better?

```
interface Student {
    public abstract void sayHi();
}

class Data implements Student {
    @Override
    public void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("method 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah its better,but i want to know the possibilities of declaration of abstract inside the interface.

Comment: @Keerthana all methods in an interface are implicitly abstract. Tell me what dont you understand about this and I can help you?

Comment: great! have fun onwards with java :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Here in the below example, I used Anonymous Class but you can use Lambda Expression also

```
interface Student {

    public abstract class Subject {

        public abstract void AbstractMethod();
        public void show(){
            System.out.println("Show Method");
        }
    }
}

class Data implements Student {

    public void ClassMethod() {
        System.out.println("method 2");
    }
}

public class NewClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Data s=new Data(); 
 Student.Subject obj=new Student.Subject(){
     public void AbstractMethod(){
            System.out.println("hi");
        }
 };
 obj.show();
 obj.AbstractMethod();
 s.ClassMethod();
}
}
```